# Cisco Catalyst 6509 Not Powering Up WS-X6716-10GE Module

Tags: cisco, switch, 10gbethernet

I just inserted a 10GbE 16 port line card into a Cisco Catalyst 6509 series switch and nothing happens(™). The chassis recognizes the new line card but doesn't boot it up. `show power` and `show modules` follow:

```
#show power
system power redundancy mode = redundant
system power total =     2771.16 Watts (65.98 Amps @ 42V)
system power used =      1837.50 Watts (43.75 Amps @ 42V)
system power available =  933.66 Watts (22.23 Amps @ 42V)
                        Power-Capacity PS-Fan Output Oper
PS   Type               Watts   A @42V Status Status State
---- ------------------ ------- ------ ------ ------ -----
1    WS-CAC-3000W       2771.16 65.98  OK     OK     on
2    WS-CAC-3000W       2771.16 65.98  OK     OK     on
                        Pwr-Allocated  Oper
Fan  Type               Watts   A @42V State
---- ------------------ ------- ------ -----
1    WS-C6509-E-FAN      150.36  3.58  OK
                        Pwr-Requested  Pwr-Allocated  Admin Oper
Slot Card-Type          Watts   A @42V Watts   A @42V State State
---- ------------------ ------- ------ ------- ------ ----- ——

5    (Redundant Sup)       -     -      282.24  6.72  -     -
6    WS-SUP720-3B        282.24  6.72   282.24  6.72  on    on
7    WS-X6716-10GE       457.80 10.90     -     -     on    off (not supported)

                        Inline         Inline         Inline         Inline
                        Pwr-Requested  Pwr-Allocated  Local-Pwr-Pool Power
Slot Card-Type          Watts   A @42V Watts   A @42V Watts   A @42V Status
---- ------------------ ------- ------ ------- ------ ------- ------ ----------
1    WS-F6K-VPWR-GE        4.62  0.11    99.54  2.37    34.44  0.82  On
2    WS-F6K-VPWR-GE        -     -        7.98  0.19    34.44  0.82  On
3    WS-F6K-VPWR-GE        -     -        7.98  0.19    34.44  0.82  On
4    WS-F6K-VPWR-GE        -     -        -     -       34.44  0.82  On
```

```
#show module
Mod Ports Card Type                              Model              Serial No.
--- ----- -------------------------------------- ------------------ -----------

  6    2  Supervisor Engine 720 (Active)         WS-SUP720-3B       
  7   16  FRU type (0x6003, 0x403(1027))         WS-X6716-10GE      

Mod MAC addresses                       Hw    Fw           Sw           Status
--- ---------------------------------- ------ ------------ ------------ -------

  7  0026.cbb2.0ee0 to 0026.cbb2.0eef   1.1   Unknown      Unknown      PwrDown

Mod  Sub-Module                  Model               Hw     Status
---- --------------------------- —————————           ------- ———

  7  Distributed Forwarding Card WS-F6700-DFC3C      1.4    PwrDown


Mod  Online Diag Status
---- -------------------

  7  Not Applicable
```

Note that I removed most modules that are irrelevant here.
Output from `show version`:

```
# show version
Cisco Internetwork Operating System Software 
IOS (tm) s72033_rp Software (s72033_rp-ENTSERVICESK9_WAN-M), Version 12.2(18)SXF15a, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1)
Technical Support: http://www.cisco.com/techsupport
Copyright (c) 1986-2008 by cisco Systems, Inc.
Compiled Tue 21-Oct-08 00:29 by kellythw
Image text-base: 0x40101040, data-base: 0x42DD4DF0

ROM: System Bootstrap, Version 12.2(17r)S2, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1)
BOOTLDR: s72033_rp Software (s72033_rp-ENTSERVICESK9_WAN-M), Version 12.2(18)SXF15a, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1)

System returned to ROM by s/w reset (SP by power-on)
System restarted at 10:27:34 MEZ Fri Dec 12 2008
System image file is "disk0:s72033-entservicesk9_wan-mz.122-18.SXF15a.bin"

cisco WS-C6509-E (R7000) processor (revision 1.2) with 458720K/65536K bytes of memory.
Processor board ID SMG0932NAAV
SR71000 CPU at 600Mhz, Implementation 0x504, Rev 1.2, 512KB L2 Cache
Last reset from power-on
SuperLAT software (copyright 1990 by Meridian Technology Corp).
X.25 software, Version 3.0.0.
Bridging software.
TN3270 Emulation software.
41 Virtual Ethernet/IEEE 802.3 interfaces
224 Gigabit Ethernet/IEEE 802.3 interfaces
1917K bytes of non-volatile configuration memory.
8192K bytes of packet buffer memory.

65536K bytes of Flash internal SIMM (Sector size 512K).
Configuration register is 0x2102
```

Comment: Can you give us a `sh ver` as well?

Comment: added output of `show version` to original post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you need a IOS upgrade.

See table 3 [here](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/prod/collateral/switches/ps5718/ps708/product_bulletin_cisco_catalyst_6500_series_16port_10gigabit_ethernet_module.html).

Comment: Grrrr. Check that like 3 times … Thx!